# st_numscalar in Mata / Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to use Stata, but am not very familiar with it.  The `forvalues` loop below is confusing.  I cannot figure out what the `st_numscalar` command in Mata is doing.  How can I view the result of this Mata line for each iteration of the loop?

```
forvalues this_month = 1 / `max_months' {

     mata: st_numscalar("apple_quota", apple_harvest[`this_month'])

}
```

Here is a functional code block that might be longer than ideal, but it does run and accurately represents the actual code I am trying to learn.

```
clear

global mt_to_kilo  = 1000
global kilo_to_lbs = 2.20462262

global apples1 = 4000
global apples2 = 2000
global apples3 = 1000
global apples4 =  700
global apples5 =  100

global apple_quota1 = $apples1 * $mt_to_kilo * $kilo_to_lbs
global apple_quota2 = $apples2 * $mt_to_kilo * $kilo_to_lbs
global apple_quota3 = $apples3 * $mt_to_kilo * $kilo_to_lbs
global apple_quota4 = $apples4 * $mt_to_kilo * $kilo_to_lbs
global apple_quota5 = $apples5 * $mt_to_kilo * $kilo_to_lbs

* to view a global variable
macro list apple_quota5
* apple_quota5:   220462.262

local max_months = 5

input month pounds total frac
1 5 100 0.05
2 10 100 0.10
3 20 100 0.20
4 30 100 0.30
5 35 100 0.35
end
list
save my_apples

* to view the data set my_apples
list `my_apples'
*     +-------------------------------+
*     | month   pounds   total   frac |
*     |-------------------------------|
*  1. |     1        5     100    .05 |
*  2. |     2       10     100     .1 |
*  3. |     3       20     100     .2 |
*  4. |     4       30     100     .3 |
*  5. |     5       35     100    .35 |
*     +-------------------------------+

clear
use "my_apples.dta", replace
putmata mf=(month frac), replace

* to view a mata data set
mata : mf
*                 1             2
*    +-----------------------------+
*  1 |            1   .0500000007  |
*  2 |            2   .1000000015  |
*  3 |            3    .200000003  |
*  4 |            4   .3000000119  |
*  5 |            5    .349999994  |
*    +-----------------------------+

mata : apple_harvest=(0 \ 0 \ $apple_quota1*mf[.,2] \ $apple_quota2*mf[.,2] \ $apple_quota3*mf[.,2]\ $apple_quota4*mf[.,2]\ $apple_quota5*mf[.,2])
mata : apple_harvest

mata : apple_harvest = apple_harvest[|19\.|]
mata : apple_harvest
*                 1
*    +---------------+
*  1 |  154323.5857  |
*  2 |  308647.1714  |
*  3 |  462970.7686  |
*  4 |  540132.5327  |
*  5 |  11023.11326  |
*  6 |  22046.22653  |
*  7 |  44092.45306  |
*  8 |  66138.68123  |
*  9 |  77161.79039  |
*    +---------------+

* What is this loop doing and how can I see the result of the mata line
* with each iteration of the loop?
forvalues this_month = 1 / `max_months' {

     mata: st_numscalar("apple_quota", apple_harvest[`this_month'])

}

* Why does the next command return the original 'my_apples' data set?
list `apple_quota5'
*     +-------------------------------+
*     | month   pounds   total   frac |
*     |-------------------------------|
*  1. |     1        5     100    .05 |
*  2. |     2       10     100     .1 |
*  3. |     3       20     100     .2 |
*  4. |     4       30     100     .3 |
*  5. |     5       35     100    .35 |
*     +-------------------------------+
```

Comment: `st_numscalar()` is a `mata` function not a Stata command. See [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals/m-5st_numscalar.pdf).

Comment: Your need to study the manuals to learn the basic stuff first. `help gs` and `help mata` will get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have figured out how to view what this loop is doing with each iteration.  I added a `display` command inside the loop.  The loop appears to simply take one value at a time from the `apple_harvest` data set.  If I add the `display` command outside the loop it simply displays the value returned by the last pass through the loop.

```
forvalues this_month = 1 / `max_months' {

     mata: st_numscalar("apple_quota", apple_harvest[`this_month'])

     display apple_quota

}

154323.59
308647.17
462970.77
540132.53
11023.113

display apple_quota

11023.113
```

An alternative approach to view the result of each iteration is shown here:

```
forvalues this_month = 1 / `max_months' {

     mata: st_numscalar("apple_quota", apple_harvest[`this_month'])
     mata: st_numscalar("apple_quota")

}
```

Comment: `apple_harvest` is not a Stata dataset but a `mata` colvector.

Comment: The loop is perverse as it just overwrites the same scalar repeatedly. Note that `display scalar(apple_quota)` is a safer way to display the scalar, as otherwise `apple_quota` might be interpreted as a variable name, or an abbreviation of a variable name, depending on what variables are in the dataset and whether variable name abbreviation is allowed. Otherwise put, scalars and variables share the same namespace.